# How to "Cut and paste" foreach loop to a method

Tags: c#

I have the following method. **My question is mainly about "cutting and pasting" the foreach loop into a method**(how to). The foreach loop determines two things. First it is responsible for adding messages to the `errorMessages` list and secondly it is responsibly for adding `test` items to the `executedTests` list. I ask this question because this is a "problem" which I encouter more often.

I want to keep my `ConvertItem` method clean so I want to "cut and paste" the foreach loop into a (private) method. This can easily be done. However, a method can only return 1 object.(I know there are ad hoc solutions which for example I use myself: `ConvertItem` returing `Result<KeuringRegel, Keuring>`). But programming languages are desinged to return void, null or just 1 object.

1 solution would be to make `errorMessages` a class property so I can call it from every method in the class. However, by far not all methods will use this `errorMessages` property so it doesn't feel justified.

```
private Result<KeuringRegel, Keuring> ConvertItem(KeuringRegel row, int rownr)
{
    List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();

    //Check A
    Debiteur debiteur = _Tools_NawContext.Debiteur.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Naam.Equals(row.Projekt, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (debiteur == null) { errorMessages.Add("Regel " + rownr + ": Debiteur.naam '" + row.Projekt + "'(row.Projekt) bestaat niet in db."); }
    //Check B, C, D and more left for brevity. Also other code, which i.e. use "row" and "rownr" left for brevity

    List<string> testNames = row.testNames.Keys.ToList();
    if (testNames.Any() == false) { errorMessages.Add("Regel " + rownr + ": bevat geen enkele test."); }

    Keuring keuring = new Keuring();//Constructor properties and code in which this "keuring" object is used left out for brevity

    List<Test> executedTests = new List<Test>();
    foreach (string testNaam in testNames)
    {
        Test test = _Tools_NawContext.Test.Include(item => item.Test2Testmethode).SingleOrDefault(item => item.Naam.Equals(testNaam, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (test == null) {
            string testValue = row.testNames[testNaam].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testValue) == false) {
                errorMessages.Add("Regel " + rownr + ": test.naam '" + testNaam + "' met waarde '" + testValue + "' bestaat niet in db.");
            }
        } else {
            executedTests.Add(test);
        }
    }

    Result<KeuringRegel, Keuring> convertResult;
    if (errorMessages.Any()) convertResult = new Result<KeuringRegel, Keuring>(row, keuring, errorMessages);
    else convertResult = new Result<KeuringRegel, Keuring>(row, keuring);
    return convertResult;
}
```

What is a recommended way of doing things? Maybe some good articles out there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about working code that need refactoring should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Apart from this you actually got your problem: your code does too much, maybe you should create two method from your loop. Or create one method returning two values via `out/ref`-keyword.

Comment: @HimBromBeere How does "should go to codereview.stackexchange.com" mean it's off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: StackOverflow and codereview are different sites, belonging both to StackExchange. It´s off course not offtopic on StackExchange where you can find nearly everything, not even related to programming. Thus a question might belong to codereview, but not to StackOverflow.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's not what I asked. Why does the existence of Code Review make it **off-topic** *on Stack Overflow*? Specifically, what section of the help-center makes this a bad-fit for Stack Overflow. Voting to Close this is the wrong choice - it's *not* off-topic here. A better use of everyones time would be a "Flag for Moderator Attention" with a custom message that "this would be a *better* fit on Code Review." (They can submit a migration request *to* Code Review, where the Code Review mods can review and approve or reject it.)

Comment: @EBrown The fact that OPs code is *working* code asking for improvement.

Comment: @HimBromBeere What about the fact that OP is asking about a specific problem on a specific piece of code. Isn't what SO is about?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The help center says nothing about "working code" being off-topic, nor "asking for improvement" being off-topic. In fact, according to [the on-topic guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), this question is a great fit. It has 1) as specific problem (how do I refactor this `for` loop), 2) has demonstrated research, and 3) is clearly answerable. Please don't go around voting to close questions *that are not close-worthy*. Flag with a custom message to tell the mods what the *best* action is, and let the system go from there.

Comment: I have no problem if this question is migrated. I also felt the question didn't fit entirely well. Creating 2 methods is a though which also crossed my mind. I am no fan of using out and ref but it is a possibility. More tips or links to good articles are still welcome

Comment: _But programming languages are desinged to return void, null or just 1 object._ That's not strictly true. What you showed yourself is one method, so is using `out` parameters. You can definitely use them for 'returning' multiple objects. Also I feel, like others mentioned, you should separate your work and create two methods.

Comment: You are right Sach, but aren't we fooling ourselfs if we use `out` and `ref` or my way of doing things(using the `Result<T1, T2>` class? Is it just not a "flag", warning us for bad design(if in my case I want, my method to be build, to return 2 types)? Real question! No punch intended..

Comment: It's hard for me to tell what you are returning, exactly, since you only instantiate `keuring` but never do anything with it. Also not sure why you're returning `row`, since the caller passed it to you and you didn't modify it. The name of your method implies that you're converting an object from one type to another, but I don't see any conversion taking place. That being said, it is common to have an `out` parameter for error messages that the caller can check separately from the return value. Sample code in English would be helpful (at least for me).

Comment: Rufus, you are right about `keuring` and `row`. I definitly do something with them but left that part of the code out for brevity since imho it isn't important for the question. Usefull comment about the `out` parameter!

Comment: I am of the opinion that this question is off-topic because it's too vague / opinion-based / asking for off-site resources. "What is a recommended why of doing things? Maybe some good articles out there?"

Comment: The approach is just wrong.  You are getting bad data and you are trying too hard to do something sensible with it.  You have no idea why it is bad data, could be a data entry mistake, could be a new rule that wasn't added to the dbase yet, could be dbase corruption.  There is never anything you can do about it, since you don't know why it is bad, no recourse but stop processing the data and alert a user about it so that he can take the proper corrective action.  You do that by throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply looking to 'move' the code inside the `foreach` loop to a method, which seems to be your direct question, you could do something like this. Note that I can't compile your code so there could be small typos and/or syntax errors, but this should give you the idea.

```
foreach (string testNaam in testNames)
{
    CantThinkOfAGoodName(testNaam, row, rownr, ref errorMessages, ref executedTests);
}

public static void CantThinkOfAGoodName(string testNaam, KeuringRegel row, int rownr, ref List<string> errorMessages, ref List<Test> executedTests)
{
    Test test = _Tools_NawContext.Test.Include(item => item.Test2Testmethode).SingleOrDefault(item => item.Naam.Equals(testNaam, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    AddErrorMessages(test, testNaam, row, rownr, ref errorMessages);
    AddExecutedTests(test, ref executedTests);
}

public static void AddErrorMessages(Test test, string testNaam, KeuringRegel row, int rownr, ref List<string> errorMessages)
{
    if (test == null)
    {
        string testValue = row.testNames[testNaam].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testValue) == false)
        {
            errorMessages.Add("Regel " + rownr + ": test.naam '" + testNaam + "' met waarde '" + testValue + "' bestaat niet in db.");
        }
    }
}

public static void AddExecutedTests(Test test, ref List<Test> executedTests)
{
    if (test != null)
        executedTests.Add(test);
}
```

But that's just diverting the problem. In my opinion the bigger issue here is that you're simply trying to do too much with one method. Let's take your original function and analyze it. To me, this is what it looks like.

```
private Result<KeuringRegel, Keuring> ConvertItem(KeuringRegel row, int rownr)
{
    // 1. Do a bunch of stuff using `debiteur`.
    //        1.1 Might add to `errorMessages`

    // 2. Get testNames

    // 3. Iterate through testNames and add to `executedTests` and/or `errorMessages`

    // 4. Based on `errorMessages` your `convertResult` is constructed and returned.
}
```

- If you look at your logic, `1.` is not related to the rest of the things other than adding `errorMessages`.
- Actions `2.` and `3.` are closely related.
- In `4.`, `executedTests` are not used.
- And `4.` is only really related to the rest of the stuff by `errorMessages`.

So my suggestion is to break apart this function into smaller functions, each of which focuses on one thing. I don't know what your problem with using `ref` and `out`, but those are there to be used when necessary, and there's nothing wrong with making use of them.

So,

- Move `1.` in one function. Pass `errorMessages` into it as `ref`.
- Combine `2.` and `3.` into one function, and again pass `errorMessages` as `ref`. You have *not* used `executedTests` anywhere in your code sample, so I assume it's not shown there.
- Move `4.` into another method, and pass to it finally your `errorMessages`. You may consider writing a small class/struct to hold the return result type.

This is only one way of doing things, but definitely, doing too much in one method is bad design. That makes it hard to maintain, debug, and test. Also, changes down the line would be a nightmare.

Comment: I marked this as my answer since it helped me greatly! One thing to note. Now I use `ref` and `out` much for the same `errorMessages` property. Is making `errorMessages` a class property an good option?